# sql inner join query can use value of outer query?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join

The below runs fine :

```
select Runs.runId,Runs.prodId,fail,Owner,
 (cast(counts.Count as decimal(4,2))) as PercentAnalysed,Language,Platform 
from Runs AS Runs Inner Join Product AS Product On Runs.prodId=Product.prodId 
    left join (SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Count', Results.runId 
            FROM Results inner join Runs on Results.runId=Runs.runId 
            WHERE Analysed = 'True' 
            GROUP BY Results.runId ) counts on counts.runId = Runs.runId
```

I want PercentAnalysed value in outer query  to be as below :

```
= [counts.Count/failCount] if failCount !=0
```

or

```
=[0] if failCount=0
```

How do I do this ?

Any idea anyone ?

Comment: What is `failcount` ?? Can you post some sample data and expected output for inner query only ??

Comment: can u just tellme how to put a condition for PercentAnalysed column in outer query..please kindly see edited question

Comment: what database are you using? sql server or mysql or indeed both systems?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `CASE` statement to get what you want.

```
SELECT 
    Runs.runId,
    Runs.prodId,
    fail, 
    Owner,
    CAST(CASE WHEN failcount <> 0 THEN counts.Count/failcount 
         WHEN failcount = 0 OR counts.Count IS NULL THEN 0
         ELSE counts.Count END AS Decimal(4,2)) PercentAnalysed,
    Language,
    Platform 
FROM
   .....
```

Comment: I tried this : CASE WHEN failcount <> 0 THEN cast(((cast(counts.Count as decimal(4,2)))/failcount *100) as decimal(4,2))
         ELSE '0' END PercentAnalysed,                              It gives me Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric :/

Comment: Remove the outer cast and see what result it gets. The conversion is failing.

Comment: ya that will work but there are 8 digits after decimal point.I want only 2 decimal places

Comment: also else part which should be =0 is not working..It shows NULL in the result

Comment: What is the change btw ?

Comment: See the CASE statement added condition for `0` value and then in first condition first division and then casting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72814/discussion-between-user1698232-and-coder-of-code).